# Proving the set of units of a ring with unity forms a group under multiplication?

Tags: group-theory

I have managed to show that all of the axioms are satisfied except the associativity axiom in order to prove $(U(R), \cdot)$ is a group.

I need to show for $a,b,c \in U(R)$ we have $(a \cdot b) \cdot c=a \cdot (b \cdot c)$.

This looks fairly straight forward but I can't seem to do it so I was wondering if anyone could give me a hand.

I'm guessing we need to use the fact that the elements are units to show they are the same but I can't quite conclude it myself yet.

Thanks.

Comment: This is an axiom for rings.

Comment: Units of a ring is a subset of the ring. So, the associativity should be satisfied by default, since multiplication is associative in the ring.

Answer (score 2):

For any $a,b,c \in R$, $a(bc)=(ab)c$ by the axioms of the ring $R$.  Thus, if $U$ is a subset of $R$, then for any $a,b,c \in U$, $a(bc)=(ab)c$.

Answer (score 0):

This is already true in the ring itself! You don't need the fact they are units.